# Why won't player 2's move method work without code for player 1?

Tags: java, move, keylistener

//I am trying to do some edits on player 2's code, so I removed everything involving player 1. But for some reason player 2 does not do anything at all without the code for player 1 in place.(it is supposed to move using the keys i, j, k and l.) So my question is "How can I get the move method for player 2 to work without the code for player1?" Also this is the best SSCCE I could provide. I removed any code that does not involve the creation of the JFrame and player 2. I also kept the code responsible for player 2's movement.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Collision extends JFrame {
```

//Jframe

```
    final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 650;
    double p1Speed = .5, p2Speed = .5;
    final int UP = 0, RIGHT = 1, DOWN = 2, LEFT = 3;
    int p1Direction = UP;
    int p2Direction = UP;
```

//Code that creates player 2

```
Rectangle p2 = new Rectangle(((WIDTH / 9) + ((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2)), (HEIGHT / 2)    
+ (HEIGHT / 10), WIDTH / 30, WIDTH / 30);

    public Collision() {

        super("Radical Racing");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);


      Move2 m2 = new Move2();
      m2.start();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);


        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fill3DRect(p2.x, p2.y, p2.width, p2.height, true);

    }
```

//This is p2 move method. I thought my error would be here but Iv'e copied this out of a book exactly.

```
private class Move2 extends Thread implements KeyListener {

        public void run() {

            addKeyListener(this);


            while (true) {

                try {

                    repaint();

                    //increase speed a bit
                    if (p2Speed <= 5) {
                        p2Speed = .2;
                    }
```

//these will move the player based off direction

```
                    if (p2Direction == UP) {
                        p2.y -= (int) p2Speed;
                    }
                    if (p2Direction == DOWN) {
                        p2.y += (int) p2Speed;
                    }
                    if (p2Direction == LEFT) {
                        p2.x -= (int) p2Speed;
                    }
                    if (p2Direction == RIGHT) {
                        p2.x += (int) p2Speed;
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(75);
                } catch (Exception e) {


                }

            }
        }

        //you must also implement this method from key listener
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyChar() == 'j') {
                p2Direction = LEFT;
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == 'k') {
                p2Direction = DOWN;
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == 'l') {
                p2Direction = RIGHT;
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar() == 'i') {
                p2Direction = UP;
            }
        }
    }

    //This starts the program by calling the constructor:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Collision();
    }
}
```

Comment: How's this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772338/why-cant-my-p2-method-work-if-i-remove-my-p1-method)? Please don't just dump your code here. Explain what is going on/not going on, and show what you've learnt when you tried to debug your code.

Comment: Are you sure the repaint() method is actually forcing the jframe to draw itself again ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but since you're only listening for certain keys, of which there are only four, I would recommend switching from using KeyListeners to Key Bindings. If you don't know what these are, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) may be of some assistance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm still new to this so if anyone thinks I should add more code or less code or a more specific question feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got one of my friends to look at it and fix for you

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RadicalRacing extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Environment size
final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 650;
// Player speed
double p1Speed = .5, p2Speed = .5;
// Integer values that represent directions
final int UP = 0, RIGHT = 1, DOWN = 2, LEFT = 3;
// These keep track of the players directions(default = up)
int p1Direction = UP;
int p2Direction = UP;

// Environment objects
Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT);
Rectangle right = new Rectangle((WIDTH / 9) * 8, 0, WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT);
Rectangle top = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(0, (HEIGHT / 9) * 8, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle center = new Rectangle((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 2.5),
(int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 2.5), (int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 5),
(HEIGHT / 9) * 4);
Rectangle obstacle = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2, (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 7),
WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle obstacle2 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 3, (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 5),
WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 4);
Rectangle obstacle3 = new Rectangle(2 * (WIDTH / 3),
(int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 5), WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 4);
Rectangle obstacle4 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 3, HEIGHT / 9, WIDTH / 30,
HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle obstacle5 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2, (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 1.5),
WIDTH / 30, HEIGHT / 4);
Rectangle finish = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 9, (HEIGHT / 2) - HEIGHT / 9,
(int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5), HEIGHT / 70);
Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH / 30, WIDTH / 30);
Rectangle p2 = new Rectangle(
((WIDTH / 9) + ((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2)), (HEIGHT / 2)
+ (HEIGHT / 10), WIDTH / 30, WIDTH / 30);

// Start the program by calling the non-static constructor.
public static void main(String[] args) { new RadicalRacing(); }

// Constructor. 
public RadicalRacing() {
super("Radical Racing"); // title of the window
setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);

// A thread is nessicary to run the environment graphics and controls
// at the same time. The graphics will run on the main thread and
// the controls will be operated on a second thread.
Movement m = new Movement();
m.start();

try { 
while(true) {
// Delay the refresh rate of the graphics.
Thread.sleep(50);
// Update the environment graphics with new positioning, etc
repaint(); 
}
} catch(Exception e) { }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
// The racetrack itself is the background of the interface.
g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

// Draw the environment outside of the race track
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.fillRect(left.x, left.y, left.width, left.height);
g.fillRect(right.x, right.y, right.width, right.height);
g.fillRect(top.x, top.y, top.width, top.height);
g.fillRect(bottom.x, bottom.y, bottom.width, bottom.height);
g.fillRect(center.x, center.y, center.width, center.height);
g.fillRect(obstacle.x, obstacle.y, obstacle.width, obstacle.height);
g.fillRect(obstacle2.x, obstacle2.y, obstacle2.width, obstacle2.height);
g.fillRect(obstacle3.x, obstacle3.y, obstacle3.width, obstacle3.height);
g.fillRect(obstacle4.x, obstacle4.y, obstacle4.width, obstacle4.height);
g.fillRect(obstacle5.x, obstacle5.y, obstacle5.width, obstacle5.height);

// Draw the starting lines.
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
// ..outer player starting line..
Rectangle lineO = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT / 2, (int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2, HEIGHT / 140);
// ..inner player starting line..
Rectangle lineI = new Rectangle(
((WIDTH / 9) + ((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2)), (HEIGHT / 2)
+ (HEIGHT / 10), (int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2,
HEIGHT / 140);
g.fillRect(lineO.x, lineO.y, lineO.width, lineO.height);
g.fillRect(lineI.x, lineI.y, lineI.width, lineI.height);

// Draw the finish line.
g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
g.fillRect(finish.x, finish.y, finish.width, finish.height);

// Draw player #1
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(p1.x, p1.y, p1.width, p1.height);

// Draw player #2
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(p2.x, p2.y, p2.width, p2.height);
}

private class Movement extends Thread implements KeyListener {

public void run() {

// Activate keyboard controls
addKeyListener(this);

try {

while(true) {
    // Delay the rate at which these variables are calculated.
    // Higher the number, the slower the race will feel.
    // Lower the number, the faster.
    // Too low and the game will be glitchy.
    Thread.sleep(75);

    // Check to see if the car hits the outside of the walls.
    // If so, slow it's speed temporarily.
    if(    p1.intersects(left)
    ||  p1.intersects(right)
    ||  p1.intersects(top)
    ||  p1.intersects(bottom)
    ||  p1.intersects(obstacle)
    ||    p1.intersects(obstacle2)
    ||  p1.intersects(p2)
    ||  p1.intersects(obstacle3)
    ||  p1.intersects(obstacle4)
    ||  p1.intersects(obstacle5))
    { p1Speed = -4; }

    if(    p2.intersects(left)
    ||  p2.intersects(right)
    ||  p2.intersects(top)
    ||  p2.intersects(bottom)
    ||  p2.intersects(obstacle)
    ||    p2.intersects(obstacle2)
    ||  p2.intersects(p1)
    ||  p2.intersects(obstacle3)
    ||  p2.intersects(obstacle4)
    ||  p2.intersects(obstacle5))
    { p2Speed = -4; }

    // If the car hits the center, slow it's speed just a little bit.
    if(p1.intersects(center)) p1Speed = -2.5;
    if(p2.intersects(center)) p2Speed = -2.5;

    // Now increase speed some.
    if(p1Speed <= 5) p1Speed += .2;
    if(p2Speed <= 5) p2Speed += .2;

    // Now move the player in the direction they're facing.
    if(p1Direction == UP)  p1.y -= (int)p1Speed;
    if(p1Direction == DOWN)  p1.y += (int)p1Speed;
    if(p1Direction == LEFT)  p1.x -= (int)p1Speed;
    if(p1Direction == RIGHT)  p1.x += (int)p1Speed;

    if(p2Direction == UP)  p2.y -= (int)p2Speed;
    if(p2Direction == DOWN)  p2.y += (int)p2Speed;
    if(p2Direction == LEFT)  p2.x -= (int)p2Speed;
    if(p2Direction == RIGHT)  p2.x += (int)p2Speed;
}

} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

// Unused methods required for implementation.
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)  { }
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) { }

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
char c = event.getKeyChar();
if(c == 'a') p1Direction = LEFT;
if(c == 's') p1Direction = DOWN;
if(c == 'd') p1Direction = RIGHT;
if(c == 'w') p1Direction = UP;

if(c == 'j') p2Direction = LEFT;
        if(c == 'k') p2Direction = DOWN;
        if(c == 'l') p2Direction = RIGHT;
        if(c == 'i') p2Direction = UP;
 }
 }

 }
```

spacing is probably off, but that doesnt matter much xD

Comment: Oh. Wooow. Thanks man. This is a LOT of different code than is in the book, but it works. I got some studying to do. LOL

Answer (score 3):

Not very good at java yet myself, but;

```
    if (p2Direction == UP) {
                    p2.y -= (int) p1Speed;
    }
    if (p2Direction == DOWN) {
                    p2.y += (int) p1Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == LEFT) {
                    p2.x -= (int) p1Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == RIGHT) {
                    p2.x += (int) p1Speed;
                }
```

shouldn't that be

```
    if (p2Direction == UP) {
                    p2.y -= (int) p2Speed;
    }
    if (p2Direction == DOWN) {
                    p2.y += (int) p2Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == LEFT) {
                    p2.x -= (int) p2Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == RIGHT) {
                    p2.x += (int) p2Speed;
                }
```

Sorry if I'm wrong :p

Comment: Yes. Your right. I don't know why I didn't see that before. I thought your edit would work but it is still not budging though.

Comment: I was playing with the code a bit more and I found out that somehow the error in my code you saw actually made my code work, but barely. If I use your edit p2 does not move at all which is weird. For some reason p2 is completely dependent on p1.

Comment: sorry, as I said before, not that great at java yet. I'll keep looking at it and maybe I'll figure it out xD

Comment: could you maybe upload the whole project somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: Joris, I posted the full code below. If you have any questions, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

//Joris, this is the full code. No SSCCE. It's right out of the book. This code has your edit included which matches the book, but if you change it to match my previous error which you corrected you will notice that p2 will move, but when p1 collides with a wall p2 will collide and that p2 goes right through walls.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Collision extends JFrame {

final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 650;
double p1Speed = .5, p2Speed = .5;
```

//these are the ints that represent directions

```
final int UP = 0, RIGHT = 1, DOWN = 2, LEFT = 3;
```

//these will keep track of the players directions(default = up)

```
int p1Direction = UP;
int p2Direction = UP;
Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT);
Rectangle right = new Rectangle((WIDTH / 9) * 8, 0, WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT);
Rectangle top = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(0, (HEIGHT / 9) * 8, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle center = new Rectangle((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 2.5), (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 2.5), 
(int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 5), (HEIGHT / 9) * 4);
Rectangle obstacle = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2, (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 7), WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT 
/ 9);
Rectangle obstacle2 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 3, (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 5), WIDTH / 10, 
HEIGHT / 4);
Rectangle obstacle3 = new Rectangle(2 * (WIDTH / 3), (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 5), WIDTH / 10, 
HEIGHT / 4);
Rectangle obstacle4 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 3, HEIGHT / 9, WIDTH / 30, HEIGHT / 9);
Rectangle obstacle5 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2, (int) ((HEIGHT / 9) * 1.5), WIDTH / 30, 
HEIGHT / 4);
Rectangle finish = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 9, (HEIGHT / 2) - HEIGHT / 9, (int) ((WIDTH / 9) 
* 1.5), HEIGHT / 70);
Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH / 30, WIDTH / 30);
Rectangle p2 = new Rectangle(((WIDTH / 9) + ((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2)), (HEIGHT / 2) 
+ (HEIGHT / 10), WIDTH / 30, WIDTH / 30);

public Collision() {
```

//the following code creates the JFrame

```
    super("Radical Racing");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
```

//start the inner class (which works on it's own because it is a thread)

```
    Move1 m1 = new Move1();
    Move2 m2 = new Move2();
    m1.start();
    m2.start();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
```

//draw the bckround for the racetrack

```
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

//When we drawthe border will be green

```
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

//the following rectangle is the start line for the outer player

```
    Rectangle lineO = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 9, HEIGHT / 2, (int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2, 
    HEIGHT / 140);
```

//the following rctangle is the start line for the inner player

```
    Rectangle lineI = new Rectangle(((WIDTH / 9) + ((int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2)), 
    (HEIGHT / 2) + (HEIGHT / 10), (int) ((WIDTH / 9) * 1.5) / 2, HEIGHT / 140);
```

//now using the rectangles, draw it

```
    g.fillRect(left.x, left.y, left.width, left.height);
    g.fillRect(right.x, right.y, right.width, right.height);
    g.fillRect(top.x, top.y, top.width, top.height);
    g.fillRect(bottom.x, bottom.y, bottom.width, bottom.height);
    g.fillRect(center.x, center.y, center.width, center.height);
    g.fillRect(obstacle.x, obstacle.y, obstacle.width, obstacle.height);
    g.fillRect(obstacle2.x, obstacle2.y, obstacle2.width, obstacle2.height);
    g.fillRect(obstacle3.x, obstacle3.y, obstacle3.width, obstacle3.height);
    g.fillRect(obstacle4.x, obstacle4.y, obstacle4.width, obstacle4.height);
    g.fillRect(obstacle5.x, obstacle5.y, obstacle5.width, obstacle5.height);
```

//set the starting line color

```
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

//the draw the starting line

```
    g.fillRect(lineO.x, lineO.y, lineO.width, lineO.height);
    g.fillRect(lineI.x, lineI.y, lineI.width, lineI.height);
```

//set the color of the finish line to yellow

```
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(finish.x, finish.y, finish.width, finish.height);
```

//set the color to blue for p1

```
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

//now draw the actual player

```
    g.fill3DRect(p1.x, p1.y, p1.width, p1.height, true);
```

//set the color to red for p2

```
    g.setColor(Color.red);
```

//now draw the actual player

```
    g.fill3DRect(p2.x, p2.y, p2.width, p2.height, true);

}

private class Move1 extends Thread implements KeyListener {

    public void run() {
```

//add the code to make the KeyListener "wake up"

```
        addKeyListener(this);
```

//now, put the code should all be in an infinite loop, so the process repeats.

```
        while (true) {
```

//now this should be in a "try" block. This will let the program exit if there is an error.

```
            try {
```

//first refresh the screen:

```
                repaint();
```

//check to see if the car hits the outside of the walls.
//If so make it slow it's speed by setting it's speed to .4.

```
                if (p1.intersects(left) || p1.intersects(right)
                        || p1.intersects(top) || p1.intersects(bottom)
                        || p1.intersects(obstacle) || p1.intersects(obstacle2)
                        || p1.intersects(p2) || p1.intersects(obstacle3)
                        || p1.intersects(obstacle4) || p1.intersects(obstacle5)) {
                    p1Speed = -4;
                }
```

//if the car hits the center, do the same as above but make the speed -2.5.

```
                if (p1.intersects(center)) {
                    p1Speed = -2.5;
                }
```

//increase speed a bit

```
                if (p1Speed <= 5) {
                    p1Speed += .2;
                }
```

//these will move the player based on direction

```
                if (p1Direction == UP) {
                    p1.y -= (int) p1Speed;
                }
                if (p1Direction == DOWN) {
                    p1.y += (int) p1Speed;
                }
                if (p1Direction == LEFT) {
                    p1.x -= (int) p1Speed;
                }
                if (p1Direction == RIGHT) {
                    p1.x += (int) p1Speed;
                }
```

//This delays the refresh rate

```
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
```

//if there is an exception (an error), exit the loop

```
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

//You must also implement this method from Key Listener

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    }
```

//You must also implement this method from key listener

```
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    }
```

//You must also implement this method from key listener

```
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
            p1Direction = LEFT;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 's') {
            p1Direction = DOWN;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'd') {
            p1Direction = RIGHT;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'w') {
            p1Direction = UP;
        }
    }
}

private class Move2 extends Thread implements KeyListener {

    public void run() {
```

//add the code to make the key listener wake up

```
        addKeyListener(this);
```

//now this should all be in an infinite loop so that the process repeats

```
        while (true) {
```

//now put the code in a try block. This will let the program exit if there is an error

```
            try {
```

//first refresh the screen

```
                repaint();
```

//check to see if the car hits the outside walls.
//if so make it slow its speed by setting it's speed to -4.

```
                if (p2.intersects(left) || p2.intersects(right)
                        || p2.intersects(top) || p2.intersects(bottom)
                        || p2.intersects(obstacle) || p2.intersects(obstacle2)) {
                    p2Speed = -4;
                }
```

//if the car hits the center, do the same as above but make the speed -2.5.

```
                if (p2.intersects(center)) {
                    p2Speed = -2.5;
                }
```

//increase speed a bit

```
                if (p2Speed <= 5) {
                    p2Speed = .2;
                }
```

//these will move the player based off direction

```
                if (p2Direction == UP) {
                    p2.y-= (int) p2Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == DOWN) {
                    p2.y+= (int) p2Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == LEFT) {
                    p2.x-= (int) p2Speed;
                }
                if (p2Direction == RIGHT) {
                    p2.x+= (int) p2Speed;
                }
```

//this delays the refresh rate:

```
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
```

//if there is an exception, exit the loop.

```
                break;

            }

        }
    }
```

//you must also implement this method from key listener

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'j') {
            p2Direction = LEFT;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'k') {
            p2Direction = DOWN;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'l') {
            p2Direction = RIGHT;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'i') {
            p2Direction = UP;
        }
    }
}
```

//This starts the program by calling the constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Collision();
}
```

}

Comment: I'll look through it and see what I can find xD